# How to make 2 parts vertices match?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm making a character, but the body and head are different parts, because I the mesh in the head is a bit more detailed and I also want the possibility to use the same character for different faces. I may be implementing morph data in the future, but probably not for the neck.

But the thing is that the intersection in the neck, does not fit well with the two parts, my objective is to make them match, and, if possible, lock this intersection from future editings.

---

It is in the beginning yet, so it's not that good, but I intend to greatly improve it in the future, adding mouth, face rig, improving the shape, and adding morph data when everything is ready.

[image]

OK, thanks for the heads up everyone! My current solution:
Alt to select and Shift D to duplicate the edge in the head, P to separate, Shift Alt to select edges in the body, X to delete, did small adjustments in the Neck, Ctrl J to to unite the neck edge and body, Ctrl E to bridge edge loops, as suggested.

If someone has also a way to lock these edges from future editings, so I can improve this part some more, let me know.

Comment: Adding some screenshots would help a lot to understand your problem.

Comment: Hi, Lucas, I'm afraid there's unlikely to be a general method for this. You'd have to be systematic about it. Please show us an illustration of the join in your particular case, so we can do the best we can.

Comment: you can use some topology technics to make the joint, but we need the file to give a try, or at least show a screenshot, or keep the head and body as separate meshes if you don't have to show the neck?

Comment: Hello, again we can't help if you don't share your file, you could try a bridge edge loops between the head and neck, and correct manually if needed, or just hide the joint under a cloth if it's possible